# Android ProgressDialog usage from non-MainActivity class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class with `DownloadPicture` method which is executing an AsyncTask. The class is not a subclass of `class MainActivity extends Activity`. How can I show ProgressDialogs by using `DownloadPicture` method? I think I can pass `MainActivity.this` to class conatructor, but is there any other way?

Comment: There are many ways. But constructor way is safe.

Comment: Use constructor and pass context to the constructor. If you providing code snippet I can explain in better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Pass your activity context to DownloadPicture class in constructor and initialize ProgressDialogs in onPreExecute() :

```
public class ProgressDialogs extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public ProgressDialogs(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "dialog title","dialog message", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do you background code here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Interface to callback to activity from your AsyncTask. And you can do whatever with ProgressDialog from your activity. Can explain in detail if you can provide your code sample.